# Web Garden at SharePoint 2013 Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, iis7

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm with 2 FrontEnd servers. Sometimes these servers consume 100% CPU and because of this, clients couldn't get response from server for a few minutes. I've set Maximum Worker Process at IIS to 3. Now it looks like working good but what are pros and cons for this? Do you recommend me to set this to it's default setting?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Web garden is not supported / recommended because "Using web gardens for content web applications will have a negative impact on page output caching and session state.  This will cause the appearance of products not working as expected.'

I would rather check which process or application causing the high CPU / memory usage, may be add more resources.

You can check this article for [Tune Web server performance (Office SharePoint Server)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/cc298550(v=office.12)#do-not-use-web-gardens)

Also check [application pool settings from this](http://mossknowledge.blogspot.com/2011/10/recommendations-for-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, Waqas. But this link is about SP2007. I couldn't find any information about SP2013 or above. Do you think that web garden is still unsupported even on SP2013?

Comment: Yes it is not supported even with latest version of sharepoint